# Why does loop based on empty vector return unique values

Tags: r, loops, vector

Suppose the following list which is a result of an api call

```
    y <- list(list(`@_fa` = "true", `$` = "Computer Science (all)", `@code` = "1700", 
        `@abbrev` = "COMP"), list(`@_fa` = "true", `$` = "Information Systems and Management", 
        `@code` = "1802", `@abbrev` = "DECI"), list(`@_fa` = "true", 
        `$` = "Library and Information Sciences", `@code` = "3309", 
        `@abbrev` = "SOCI"))

> y

[[1]]
[[1]]$`@_fa`
[1] "true"

[[1]]$`$`
[1] "Computer Science (all)"

[[1]]$`@code`
[1] "1700"

[[1]]$`@abbrev`
[1] "COMP"


[[2]]
[[2]]$`@_fa`
[1] "true"

[[2]]$`$`
[1] "Information Systems and Management"

[[2]]$`@code`
[1] "1802"

[[2]]$`@abbrev`
[1] "DECI"


[[3]]
[[3]]$`@_fa`
[1] "true"

[[3]]$`$`
[1] "Library and Information Sciences"

[[3]]$`@code`
[1] "3309"

[[3]]$`@abbrev`
[1] "SOCI"
```

If I run the following loop, I get a vector, `my_vec`, of the values stored in `$@code`. However, these are duplicated three times, i.e.:

```
for (i in 1:length(y)) {
  
  #extract
  out <- y[[i]]$`@code`
  my_vec <- c(out, my_vec)
  
}

> my_vec
[1] "3309" "1802" "1700" "3309" "1802" "1700" "3309" "1802" "1700"
```

If I create an empty character vector before running the loop, it gives me the *unique* values:

```
my_vec <- character() #empty vector

for (i in 1:length(y)) {
  
  #extract
  out <- y[[i]]$`@code`
  my_vec <- c(out, my_vec)
  
}

> my_vec
[1] "3309" "1802" "1700"
```

The last result is what I need, but I am afraid it does other things that I am not aware of - and I am using it in a very large loop, so I want to be sure that no un-intended things happen!

Can anyone explain the difference - why does making the empty vector return unique values?

Comment: The code won't run unless `my_vec` exist (Try in a new session). The reason why you see the output several times is that you're appending the results to the previous results every time you run the script. The `my_vec <- character()` resets it.

Comment: Ah... Embarrasing! Thank you, that explains it

Comment: We're always learning :) Alternative solution: `sapply(y, "[[", "@code")`

Comment: Or if you need the loop for whatever reason, it's much faster NOT to append. Instead initialize the vector at the correct length and put into the correct positions accordingly. I.e. `my_vec <- character(length(y)); for (i in seq_along(y)) my_vec[i] <- y[[i]]$`@code`

Comment: Uh, much faster is very desirable for me, thank you so much @harre

Comment: Last input, if the API-results are structured in as nice a way as it looks, it might as well be a handy option for you to turn it into a dataframe (depending on what you want to do next): `dplyr::bind_rows(y) |> dplyr::select(`@code`)` :-)

Comment: That is way simpler than my intricate way of pasting that currently comes after! Big help, very much appreciated!